# Running several commands in same CMD from Python but wait earlier to finish first

Tags: python, cmd, os.system

I need to open up CMD in Windows from python code and run several different commands in there but they have to wait earlier command to finish first before inputting the next one. They all take different X amount of times to finish. And also if possible, the CMD window could stay actively open the whole time. How could this be done?

For example:

```
import os

# Let's say this installs something and takes x amount of time
command1 = "make install"
# Let's say this command configures paths for example
command2 = "configure"
# Lastly we could check folders for example
command3 = "ls"

os.system("start /wait cmd /c {}".format(command1))
os.system("start /wait cmd /c {}".format(command2))
os.system("start /wait cmd /c {}".format(command3))
```

Comment: `os.system` is a blocking call, so the ordering should already be there.

Comment: Why have `start /wait` there? Can't you run `cmd /c {}` by itself?

Comment: By the way, if this is all you're doing, why use Python? A `.bat` file is much simpler and also meets the requirement to keep the same CMD window open.